# Is there a size limit to reduceRegion in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, reducers

I want to use some points (point_695 in this case) to extract their values in a time series trajectory of Landsat 8 image scenes from 2014-01-01 to 2014-05-15. When I use `reduceRegions()` to do the extraction, it only got return when I use

`point_695.limit(2) or point_695.limit(2)`

When I select more than 2 points, the whole `reduceRegions` function does not work and returns nothing. My question is:

Is there a size limit to run the `reduceRegions()` function? If so, how can I revise the script? ps: My points are located sparsely in a very large area.

Here is the main problem part of my code:

```js
var probavProjection = ee.ImageCollection('VITO/PROBAV/C1/S1_TOC_100M').first()
                .select('NDVI').projection(); 

var ndvitimeseries = dataset.map(function(image) {
   var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4'])
  return ndvi
})

var point_ndvi = ndvitimeseries.map(function(image){
  var date = image.getString("system:index").slice(12)
  return image.reduceRegions({ 
      collection:point_695**.limit(2)**,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), //andrei: mean
      scale: 100,
      crs: probavProjection,
    }).map(function(f){return f.set("date", date)})
})
print(point_ndvi.first())
point_ndvi = point_ndvi.flatten()//.distinct(["Field1","date"]);
print(point_ndvi.**limit(2)**,"flatten")
```